# Pros/Cons of incorporating multiple database types into same project

Tags: database, mongodb, cassandra, scaling

I'm beginning to pursue my first online project that I am planning will need to scale as such I have opted for a NoSQL DB. Some reading into this and modeling of what my queries would look like and there are two databases I am considering. Cassandra seems like the right choice for item lookups by keyword but MongoDB sounds like the right choice for initially entering the data in as it can retain the account structure in document form.

This split decision has left me wondering: Are there any major companies that use multiple database types for storage of different items as in using both Cassandra and Mongo together?

I would think scaling up would be more difficult but are the added benefits (if there are any) worth the trouble? I'm not the expert on this. I'm hoping you are. Thanks in advance for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 2):

Cassandra can handle both use cases so you can use the same database for your purposes.

Stargate (https://stargate.io/) is an open-source API platform which provides a data gateway to Cassandra with REST API, GraphQL API, Document API and even native CQL access.

The Document API lets you save and search schemaless JSON documents to/from Cassandra directly from your app.

You can try it out for free on [Astra](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) with no credit card required. In just a few clicks, you'll be able to launch a Cassandra cluster with Stargate pre-configured so you can use the Document API straight out-of-the box and build a proof-of-concept app immediately without having to worry about downloading/installing/configuring a Cassandra cluster.

There are even sample apps you can access straight from the Astra dashboard so you can see Stargate in action. For more info, see [Using the Document API on Astra](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/document-api.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple database technologies in the same project is somewhat common nowadays and it is called "Polyglot persistence".

Many people use this method to take advantage of multiple systems - and as you mentioned Cassandra is right for somethings and something else (maybe MongoDB) is best for something else, so using a combination can give the advantage of both worlds.

Scaling, Replication, Support can be more costly when you use multiple technologies because you need expertise in both to support.

So if you really have use cases where Cassandra wont be a good choice and you have some primary use cases where Cassandra is the best choice then yes, going with two databases can be the best option provided you are ready to take the trouble of supporting two systems.